# Format datetime into days

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am wanted to format my data from

```
TO_DATE('16-Jun-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

to display into something like

[image]

I am unsure what func in oracle should i use to make this change

Comment: you can mark a green tick on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should store dates as dates, but you seem to want something like:

```
select to_char(TO_DATE('16-Jun-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Dy DD Month    YYYY')
```

I don't know how many spaces you want . . . or even if the year is in a separate column.

Comment: the year is on the same column but its just spaced out i think thank you Gordon !

Answer (score 0):

Even this will do:

```
select TO_CHAR( DATE'2019-07-16', 'DY  DD MON,RRRR' ) from dual
```